# Two-directional carousel ViewPager

Tags: android, carousel, android-viewpager

How to create **2-directional infinite** ViewPager? In the existing one the position of the element can be >= 0, but not < 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The viewpager has an adapter. The adapter has a getView method. In the getView, use "position" modulo the number of elements in your list. Let getCount return a high number, and start the viewpager somewhere in the middle of the range.
It's not infinite, but almost.

Comment: Actually, you can start the list close to the number it returns in getCount, because if the user scrolls right, you can increase the number that getcount returns. But why bother..